# C# Problems uploading files to a HTTP website

Tags: c#, http, web, uploading

I'm writing a program that needs to upload an access database file (.accdb) to a website.

This is what I currently have:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    try
    {
        WebClient Client = new WebClient();      
        Client.UploadProgressChanged += 
            new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
        Client.UploadFileAsync(
            new Uri ("http://elsumowebhost.freehostingcloud.com/"),
            "POST", 
            "c:\\test\\Testupload.txt");           
    }
    catch(Exception a)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(a+"");
    }
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString()+"%";
}
```

According to the program the file is uploaded to the website(**the progress bar reaches 100%**), but when I go and check the file is not there. 
Is there a reason for this? Why doesn't my file reach the website?

Answer (score 1):

You need somekind of solution on the server side to receive and save the file you send from your program.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Dispose the WebClient! Second: wrap it all in the try-catch and switch to the UploadFile version, not the async, just to see if it does work. Then try again.

I have assumed that the website you're uploading to is already existing. Is that the case that  there's no code on the other side to save the file? Do you have access to site logs?

Comment: Hi thanks for the help.. I did as you said with no success.

Yes the website is already existing and unfortunately i don't have access to the logs. What needs to be done on the website for it to allow file uploads. (I'm new with web development)

Comment: I would create a handler for that.

Comment: That depends very much on what kind of server it is. But you need somekind of code to fetch the "uploaded" data and save it to the server disk.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, on http://freehostingcloud.com/ you have only php. With this I cannot help. And also, judging from the structure of the original url you tried to post the file to - this couldn't work. You've seen some progress, because that's how post work, but it wasn't really "saving" any file. So if you want to implement uploading file and don't know php, first get some asp.net capable hosting.

Comment: Everyone starts from somewhere.